# Getting Started using square with php

Tags: square-connect

I'm looking at ordering a square contactless card reader, I need to be able to charge access to an upcoming event which will be a fixed amount of £5 GBP. I need to keep it as simple as possible, I don't need to take any information from the user i simply want to them to scan their phone or card on the reader to gain access.

Is something like this possible with Square? I have some basic PHP Knowledge would be easy to do in that, Are there any starter templates out there which i can modify?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would still need to interact with a device. At this time you cannot do a totally automated experience like you described.